# Is every loop homotopic to a smooth loop?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm studying Differential Topology for a lecture, and we're using Guillemin & Pollack as the text for the lectures. In section 1.6, they define 'simply connected manifold' as a manifold $X$ in which every smooth map $f: S^1 \to X$ is homotopic to a constant map. However, the most general definition of fundamental group has as elements equivalence classes of *continuous* loops. Assuming both definitions are equivalent for manifolds, we would need some result like: **every continuous loop in a manifold is homotopic to a smooth loop**. Also, Sard's theorem implies that given any smooth map $f: X \to Y$, where $\dim{X} < \dim{Y}$, its image has measure 0. Considering strange continuous functions such as Peano curves, it seems even more confusing for me.

Comment: Yes, every continuous map between manifolds can be homotoped to a smooth map. Given a metric on the target manifold, you can actually make this approximation as close as desired. Yes, Sard's theorem has the implication as stated. What's your question there? It's a quick proof that $\pi_k(X) = 0$ when $ k < \dim X$

Comment: question was if it is true that every map is homotopic to a smooth map. I was wondering if you could indicate to me some sketch of a proof of this fact.

Comment: Rob's answer has a sketch for maps out of 1-manifolds. In general, you can do similar stuff with charts on a manifold, and using bump functions in each chart!

Comment: @OsamaGhani: I think the question is only about loops (i.e., maps out of 1-manifolds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any continuous path $p : [0, 1] \to \Bbb{R}^n$ is homotopic to the straight line path from $p(0)$ to $p(1)$. Hence any continuous path $q : [0, 1] \to X$ where $X$ is a smooth manifold can be subdivided into a finite sequence of paths $q_i : [t_i, t_{i+1}] \to X$, $i = 1, \ldots k$ that are all smooth. Now by looking at a chart around each $t_i$ with $1 < i < k$ you can adjust the $q_i$ to make their union smooth everywhere.